# How to Create serviceEndpoint in Azure devops by python?

Tags: python, azure, azure-devops

How to Create service Endpoint in AzureDevops by python?

I like to import a repo from one project to another. I have to pass serviceEndpoint in POST request body. How to create serviceEndpoint?

Comment: Have you considered this? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/serviceendpoint/endpoints/create?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0

Comment: @TejasNagchandi what values should I give at "scheme"(is it PAT) and "Url"(repo URL) in request body.